# Get overall sum having partial data

Tags: statistics

I have partial data of online game ingame sales. I know the data for N users. The overall game  users count is M which is about 6 times greater than N. I can calculate overall revenue for N users. But I need to calculate estimated revenue for all M users. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think your partial data is representative of the whole population and $M$ is known, then take your revenue amount for $N$ users and multiply by the ratio ${M \over N}.$